How can mages supply themselves with magic?
Mages must ingest a special magic liquid before using magic. Most mages use jars, but opening a jar takes time which is not something close combat mages have. How can a device that allows them to drink this liquid at will be designed in a robust and unburdensome fashion? The tech level is early industrial revolution. This device should operate without the use of magic, should NOT require the invention of plastic to take place, and shouldn't be too large to easily wear without discomfort.

What's wrong with a vial, or a canteen, or a waterskin? We have documentary evidence that in the classical antiquity they used small vials for the purpose.

A vial can easily be shot out of your hand or broken. It can be shattered if your enemy knows where you keep your vials or dropped in the heat of battle, not to mention that you need to take one hand away from fighting to uncap and drink your magic. It works for Asterix because encounters are made extremely short by the magic potion, which isn't the case for my mages.

All right then, a waterskin it will be.

For what it's worth, it can be an interesting mechanism in your story where you know how and when these mages take them. As @AlexP made you think, it gives weaknesses to the mages, as well as strength. Will you shoot the mage or the bottle? Won't the vial be like reloading a weapkn, before unleashing hell? Will individual mages have their own approach to quickly drink vials, like on strings as a necklace? Or maybe as a mag in a strap on the jacket? It'll offer individuality to your mages as well as something to balance them. Especially if no standards have been invented yet for their case.

Is this a worldbuilding question? The first thing that came to my mind was this. Every solution we come up with will have pros and cons. VTC:Too Story-Based until you come up with a definitive list of conditions you will not live with to help guide us in your quest. Or, better still, you could ask this question in the Story Tellers Corner chat room where you can ask any story question with impunity.

... And if you insist on leaving this question on Main, take the time to explain specifically and in detail how your mages are employed in combat. At the moment it feels like you expect them to be in a front-line charge, in which case the problem isn't delivery of the fluid but how you've balanced your magic system. (Super-slow magazine reload of a weapon that has a super fast discharge.)

Rubber tube and a water skin sewn into vestments.  Vulcanized rubber was developed early/mid 1800's rubber is thousands of years old.

I’m positive that this is a duplicate, but can’t find the original question. Does anyone else recall a semi recent question about super soldiers needing to ingest a drug or potion in combat, and how to make that practical?

@JBH they are employed in close combat, as you might have gleaned from the fact that they are called close combat mages. Because guns are dangerous they are not in the front but are used for strategic elimination of enemy targets with magic and melee weapons. Regardless, having both hands to fight is valuable. Something like that also came to my mind, but I can't see how it could work without the lightweight waterproof plastic and made with very early machining capabilities.

@IMP9024 The reason I asked you to be specific about that is that close combat requires rapid ammunition refills. The fact that people are drinking potions means there's a problem. You have an imbalance in your magic system. You have a support dependency (aka, artillery) and you're trying to use it on the front line. Like all artillery that's been used on the front line, it's quickly destroyed. You either need to move your mages to the back or throw out the need to drink a potion on the front line. Or live with AlexP's logical conclusion that they drink from skins or canteens.

Sorry, I don't follow. Are you trying to say that mages are artillery? I specifically said that they are for close combat at melee ranges. Where's the artillery? And why would having to drink a potion mean the magic system is imbalanced?

If you have a good enough shot to shoot a vial out of a mages hand, just shoot the mage.

@DanielB no doubt mine

An athlete's hydration bladder.
(Sometimes referred to as a "Platypus")

You could absolutely make something like this without plastic. The bladder itself can be a standard waterskin.
The drinking tube is slightly more complicated, but you've got options. Rubber's been around for a couple hundred years. If you want to get really hardcore, use metal, either with some cunning joints, or as a single "fitted" piece designed specifically for the mage who uses it. Clay/fired pottery is another option and can be surprisingly strong.

The answer is Jello Shots
(As any frat bro would tell you, there are a remarkable number of problems solvable with jello shots)
The parallel needs of a combat mage and one of my beloved party-going frat brothers are remarkably similar:

Must have easy availability for critical fluids
Needs hands free for casting (spells / ping pong balls, into meatbags and solo cups respectively
Wants to avoid spillage in chaotic environments
Requires quick, efficient delivery method
Storage must be portable and robust
The ability to pre-prep large amounts of doses the night before a rager is key

Gelatinizing agents have been used for a long time. Gelatin is fortunately already appropriate for the early industrial era, but I might prefer agar or carrageenan, since they're less likely to get sloppy on a hot day. Large batches of the potion would be prepared in advance, and then poured into waxed paper cartridges, or small wax bottles, then left to cool over night.

Creative commons
The advantages are numerous:

No spillage during combat movements, or if dropped, unlike liquid potions
One handed consumption
No glass containers to break
Waxed paper cartridges are lightweight and disposable
Solid wax cartridges are durable and

A combat mage could carry their "power shots" in a leather bandolier across their chest, much like how one of my noble frat brethren might wear a beer bandolier to a tailgate. Simply grab, tear, squeeze, and you're powered up for your next spell. Nicer bandoliers might have metal tubes that the cartridges slip into, for greater protection.
If you want a bonus worldbuilding detail, perhaps the gelatin also helps moderate the magic absorption rate - preventing the magical equivalent of a sugar crash that might come from chugging straight potion. Just as the modern party-goer knows that jello shots hit different than straight liquor, the combat mage appreciates a slow and sustained release of magical energy.

A bandolier equipped with diminutive, robust glass or metal tubes, each containing the elixir of magic, would be an effective solution. Each tube could be fitted with a slender metal cap that snaps open upon pressing. Mages could swiftly grasp one, open it in a single motion, and consume the elixir without disrupting their momentum. This design is both ingenious and aligns seamlessly with the early industrial aesthetic.
